# I get an error message saying that it takes 1 positional argument but 2 are given, but when I remove said code, It wont run

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is all of the code for this program.
Most of this is from this link: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/reply_bot.html
Some of it is my own, but some of the code is from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FpqXyJsd1s

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

import praw
import time
import random
from praw.models.listing.mixins import submission
from praw.models.reddit.submission import SubmissionFlair 
from praw.reddit import Submission, Subreddit

def __init__(self, submission, trick):
    self.submission = submission
    self.trick = SubmissionFlair(submission).choices("blah")   

trick = SubmissionFlair(submission).choices('blah')

compliment = ['More blah', 'blah blah blah', 'blah!', 'blah?', 'blah.']

def main():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        user_agent="blah",
        client_id="this is filled in the things",
        client_secret="same here",
        username="also here",
        password="same thing here",
    )
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("blah")
    for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
        process_submission(submission)

def process_submission(submission):
    normalized_title = submission.title.lower()
    if Subreddit.new(limit = 5):
        for question_phrase in trick:
            if question_phrase in normalized_title:
                reply_text = random.shuffle(0,(compliment)-1)
                print(f"Replying to: {submission.title}")
                submission.reply(reply_text)
                time.sleep(3600)
                return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My problem is with this line of code:

```
trick = SubmissionFlair(submission).choices('TRICK')
```

or line 15; when I run the code, I get this error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Offic\Desktop\pythonprojects.py> & C:/Users/Offic/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/python.exe c:/Users/Offic/Desktop/pythonprojects.py/redditbotpart2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Offic\Desktop\pythonprojects.py\redditbotpart2.py", line 15, in <module>
    trick = SubmissionFlair(submission).choices('TRICK')
TypeError: choices() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

ive tried removing that line of code, but it gives me a yellow line on vscode on line, and when I run the code without that line, it just wont run. Ive also tried removing line 13 as well, and gives me the following error message:

```
TypeError: choices() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I apologize if this is a simple question, im a beginner

Comment: Have you tried to remove the argiment "blah" from the .choices()?

Comment: Did you actually went over the docs you linked to? The method [`choices`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/submissionflair.html#praw.models.reddit.submission.SubmissionFlair.choices) doesn't take any arguments (except the implied `self`)...

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You posted 35 lines of code for a two-line question.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  The documentation you reference shows you the problem, and there are thousands of examples on line, including many on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You also haven't given us any idea what you expect your additional argument to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

This [documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/submissionflair.html#praw.models.reddit.submission.SubmissionFlair) says that choices does not take any arg (apart from self which goes automatically when you call it via object).

You should call it like `choices()` and not `choices(blah)`

Comment: ok, I just removed 'blah' from choices(), and now i get this syntax error: `AttributeError: module 'praw.models.listing.mixins.submission' has no attribute 'subreddit'`

Comment: Create a second question with updated code which can be reproed.